# How do I calculate income tax on income that includes freelancing?

Tags: income-tax, india

I'm a salaried person with an annual income of around 4 L/annum. Besides this, I also do freelancing which gives me some 2L/annum. A part of my income is deducted as tax from my employer at a rate of 20%, since he's not aware of my freelance income. But, since my total income is above 5 L/annum, how should I calculate tax? If I pay tax for my freelance income, is there any way that my employer will come to know about my freelance income? Is there any for him to know of my additional income using my PAN ID?

Answer (score 2):

You are liable to pay tax on the entire amount 4 + 2 = 6 lacs.
You can declare the additional income to your employer and he will appropriately deduct the tax and deposit it with Income Tax Department.

The employer is not obligated or responsible to know your additional income.

The responsibility of declaring the additional income and paying taxes accordingly is your responsibility.

Edit 1:
The employer gives a Form16 that shows the salary paid and the tax deducted.
One has to file returns and there are section where you declare income from other sources. In this case declare it as 2 lacs. As there is additional tax obligation, one has to pay advance tax if the amount is more than 10, 000/- [or self assessment tax while filing returns]. The tax can also be paid online using the gateway of various Bank. Alternatively one can get the form, from local Income Tax office and pay the tax by cash in any Bank.

Refer to the Income Tax India Govt website for more details.

Edit 2:
The form 16 is applicable when someone else deducts tax at source and deposits with Govt. If you directly pay tax, there is no form 16 needed. You have to declare this as "Advance Tax Paid" in the relevant section of the Tax Returns form "Sahaj"

Edit 3:
The date for advance tax is 15th of every last month of the quarter [ie 15th June, 15 Sept, 15th Dec, 15th Mar]. Refer to http://law.incometaxindia.gov.in/DitTaxmann/IncomeTaxActs/2005ITAct/section211.htm

Comment: so if i pay a tax from a bank gateway, how will i get a form 16 for dat

Comment: ok..what are the dates to pay advance tax.And how to calculate advance tax before getting our full income for that year.I mean it may vary.And one more thing.Is there any way that my employer can know about my other sources of income using my pan id

Comment: How is it relevant whether your employer knows or not? Its your obligation to pay tax on additional source of income and not employers. Even if he knows he is not required to deduct any tax, unless you request him to rather than paying tax directly.

Comment: actually i don't want him to know that i'm doing some freelancing other than being employed with his firm.Its not advised for employers of this firm to do any other work outside of the company work.if found may cause some legal actions as per the terms and conditions with firm

Comment: and 1 more doubt ...my additional income till now is 80000, but i didn't pay any tax as of on 15th june.Will dat cause any penalities.what if i pay tax from 15th sep onwards.

Comment: "Actually you don't want your employer to know ..." Sorry this site does not advice or encourage any wrong doings. PAN is not the only way your employer would know, there are various other mechanism...

Comment: Refer to the link, it gives out the percentage of tax to be deposited. Consult a Tax advisor on exact liability. Also if you have missed paying, there is a provision of penalty & interest at the rate of 1% of tax amount.